Take a nap (SLEEP) at the end of each epoch
I wonder if that is a training strategy that if we could take a SLEEP() function at the end of each epoch.
for i in range(epochs):
    model.train()
    loss = ...
    loss.backward()
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        # evaluation
    model.sleep()

While the model is sleeping, it may be possible to perform some operations on the model parameters. I guess maybe something like regularization or checking the continuity of the vectors. (The dreams in sleeping contain continuous pictures) Are there any papers discussing this sleep strategy?
I come up with this idea last night when I was sleeping.
